# Anyone else have this problem?: googling developer related issues returns foreign language documentation

Tags: documentation, google

I'm not sure where else to take this issue...

Basically, I've noticed in past weeks that generic searches for apex/vf documentation is returning the correct SF documentation.. but in Japanese.

Salesforce provides their developer documentation in several languages - in fact, you can change the article language on the fly via a dropdown on their [Apex workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm)

The weird thing is, I haven't ever used the Japanese language version of their docs, but for some reason a couple weeks ago that's what started showing up on any Google search results for dev documentation. Weirder still, the english version doesn't show up lower in the list or anything.

Here's a screenshot of the results of a google search for 'Try catch apex'.
[image]

Has anyone else had this issue? Is this a client-side issue that I can resolve, or has google just been messing with the SEO of the different language versions of their docs?

Comment: Every once and awhile I will google something and I'll get what looks like Japanese mid-page or so.  Never first result though.  Doesn't happen often enough to annoy me.

Comment: Yes, it's been happening to me with increasing frequency. Not sure who's gaming the SEO but it sure is annoying!

Comment: That's definitely a problem with Google, and not one that we can solve directly. Maybe there's a way to report a bug?

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me. Salesforce may drive me to insanity one day, but today is not that day.

Comment: This is good question but i am not sure if its right fit for the SFSE?

Comment: Just ran into this problem today. Does Salesforce Docs site need to send a `Content-Language` header back with response to let the client know? Google could use that to index appropriately, although I'm sure Google could detect the language by analysing the content anyway.

Comment: I've found that even inside of Salesforce's docs this happens. For example when I go here https://developer.salesforce.com/search?q=apex:iframe the first result is mysteriously in Japanese but the rest are English. I feel like I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Recently started getting Chinese on many pages. this is crazy. but most of the things are in English and never had a 'big' problem to read docs.

Comment: I don't know if the issue was discovered yet, but today I read this google article about content hijacking: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/fixing_the_japanese_keyword_hack and after some time this could be the cause

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that needs to be worked out between Salesforce (the company) and Google. Either SF needs to change the way they serve multi-language pages to match what Google is expecting, or Google needs to adjust its indexing to handle what SF is doing.

And maybe one or both of those things has already happened, because I haven't seen this.

Answer (score -5):

I think it depends on salesforce instance where you log-in. After that chrome takes the language of the salesforce instance where you logged-in.

Please check the instance of the org where you logged and confirm if it Japanese/chinese.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @Arun, I don't think this is relevant, as I don't have to be logged into SF (or SF's support site) for google to return Japanese results. That said, our business is located in the U.S. and our org is english only.